# How do I auto-generate an ID in my WPF DataGrid when entering in new fields

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, auto-generate

What I want to do is when the person goes to enter in a new data to create a new row in the database / `DataGrid`. I want the ID to be auto generated. I do not want the users to be putting in their own ID. Except, I don't really have any idea of how to do this.

I have tried researching on how to do this, and have had no luck at all.

This is what I have for adding the rows into the `DataGrid` and database.

```
private void addRows_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlstring);
    conn.Open();
    string Query = "Insert into [ASSIGNMENT] ([AssignmentID], [Description], [TotalPoints], [PointsEarned], [GradeBucketID]) Values('" + this.txtAssignment.Text + "','" + txtDescription.Text + "','" + txtTotalPoints.Text + "','" + txtPointsEarned.Text + "', '" + txtGradeBucket.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand createCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
    createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Updated");
    conn.Close();
}
```

**Note:** This is `WPF` and a `DataGrid`. Not `WinForm` and `DataGridView`. There is a difference.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way is to configure you table in database to auto generate the key I mean **Identity** and not insert any value for unique column and let the table to auto generate it

Answer (score 0):

Just define the ID filed in the database as an automatic field.
In Access is an AutoNumber, in MySQL is to give the auto_increment attribute to the field and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [globally unique identifier (GUID)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate a unique id :

```
var ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```